# enviar email no codigneter usando SMTP GMAIL LOCALHOST

Tags: codeigniter

Não consigo enviar email, da a mensagem de erro abaixo. Estou usando xampp, via localhost.

```
ello: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sun, 24 Apr 2016 10:01:58 -0300
From: "Meu" <flavio@mlblimp.com.br>
Return-Path: <flavio@mlblimp.com.br>
To: flaviomlblimp547@gmail.com
Subject: assunto de e-mail
Reply-To: "flavio@mlblimp.com.br" <flavio@mlblimp.com.br>
X-Sender: flavio@mlblimp.com.br
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <571cc3c6b9c54@mlblimp.com.br>
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

```
function enviar_mensagem(){
          $mensagem = "Nome:".$this->input->post('txt_nome').br();
          $mensagem .= "E-mail:".$this->input->post('txt_email').br();
          $mensagem .= "Menagem:".$this->input->post('txt_mensagem').br();

            $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'flaviomlblimp547@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'XXXXXXX';
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['validate'] = TRUE;
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";


          $this->load->library('email', $config);

          $this->email->from('flavio@mlblimp.com.br', 'Meu');
          $this->email->to('flaviomlblimp547@gmail.com');
          $this->email->subject('assunto de e-mail');
          $this->email->message($mensagem);
          if ($this->email->send()) {
              $this->load->view('sucesso_envia_contato');
          }
          else {
              print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
          }
        }
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português. Faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como o site funciona.

Comment: Amigo, usa a api do mandrill. Com ela você pode enviar emails através de requisição post, então nem é precisos configurar o smtp no seu servidor.

Comment: Siga esse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho&index=507&list=PL1C87CCACA68A94A3). Ele mostra passo a passo, é bem explicativo.
Eu fiz o mesmo projeto ha um tempo atrás usando Apache e xammp.

Answer (score 2):

O Google passou a rejeitar envio de e-mails usando uma aplicação não autorizada.

Se você der uma olhada na sua caixa de entrada do Gmail, terá um e-mail do Google informando que uma tentiva de login foi impedida.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=pt-BR

Do link acima:

> "Você precisa configurar um registro SPF para o domínio com o endereço
>   IP do dispositivo ou aplicativo, de modo a garantir que os
>   destinatários não rejeitem os e-mails enviados por esse endereço.
>   Também é preciso adicionar esse endereço IP à caixa Lista de e-mails
>   autorizados no Google Admin Console. Por exemplo, se o endereço do
>   dispositivo de envio for 123.45.67.89, adicione esse endereço ao
>   registro SPF sem remover os servidores de e-mail do Google Apps do
>   registro: v=spf1 ip4:123.45.67.89 include:_spf.google.com ~all"

UPDATE: Você até pode usar o seu gmail para o envio, porém não poderá usar um domínio próprio como e-mail FROM, para isso você precisa ativar o uso de aplicações menos seguras [neste link](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps) e alterar o seu código:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
```

Comment: vale lembrar que vc vai precisar ter acesso as configurações de DNS para poder apontar o spf, os envios de seu localhost saem pelo seu router ou seja é o ip válido dele que precisa estar configurado como ip permitido pelo google, se o seu ip for dinâmico esqueça gafanhoto, para o google vc é um SPAMMER

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, sua configuracao do host do gmail esta incorreta.
Segue a configuracao correta, tente essa.

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```